# WCF Setting in code vs app.config

Tags: wcf, settings, app-config

If I set a setting in the app.config and in code which one will get used?

Example:

```
Dim instance As ServiceThrottlingBehavior
Dim value As Integer

value = instance.MaxConcurrentInstances

instance.MaxConcurrentInstances = value
```

VS

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
     <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior  name="Throttled">
          <serviceThrottling 
           maxConcurrentInstances="1"
          />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As configuration is loaded first, your code will override the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Imperative run-time code trumps declarative settings.